# How to implement Google Tag Manager on Webflow setup?

Tags: google-tag-manager, webflow

I have a problem embedding the Google Tag Script on my page. 
Here's what I did:

1. Placed the initial Google Tag Manager script on the Custom Code > Head Code
   [image]
2. Added Embedded HTML code on the Designer Editor and placed the last Google Tag Script

[image]

3. Published to my test subdomain.

But after refreshing my page I have a 404 error regarding the GTM
[image]

Can you help me with this? Because on the Google Tag Setup the 2nd script should be placed after the opening of the body tag. And on my case, the embedded HTML code I generate has a `<div>` tag and inside it is my 2nd Google Tag Manager script.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue,
The issue is on the Google Tag Container. 
Currently it is not publish but when I changed it to publish it fixed my issues.